# How to add an image to a CSS popup box

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="showUserInfo noPrint" id="showUserInfo">
    <div class="hidOverflow brClear fullWidth vertAlignT allAroundPad">
        <div class="setFloatL hidOverflow vertAlignT" style="width: 55%;">Login User: </div>
        <div class="setFloatL hidOverflow vertAlignT" style="width: 45%; color: #FFF;"><asp:Label ID="lblUserN" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidOverflow brClear fullWidth vertAlignT allAroundPad">
        <div class="setFloatL hidOverflow vertAlignT" style="width: 55%;">Workgroups: </div>
        <div class="setFloatL hidOverflow vertAlignT" style="width: 45%; color: #FFF;">
            <ul class="ulO" id="ulO" runat="server">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidOverflow brClear fullWidth vertAlignT allAroundPad" id="dvAdmin" runat="server">
        <div class="setFloatL hidOverflow vertAlignT" style="width: 55%;">Admin Status: </div>
        <div class="setFloatL hidOverflow vertAlignT" style="width: 45%; color: #FFF;"><asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgIsAdmin" ClientIDMode="Static" ImageUrl="~/theImages/admin_yes.png" CssClass="adminImg" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.showUserInfo {
    position: absolute;
    background: #243942;
    border: 4px solid #E55302;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: 45px;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 350px;
    top: 55px;
    z-index: 200;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #C0C0C0;
    display: none;
}
```

Output:

[image]

I am looking to add an image to the left corner which goes outside of the box to look something like this:

[image]

I tried to change the HTML to the following but the image goes inside the box:

```
<div class="showUserInfo noPrint" id="showUserInfo">
    <div class="hidOverflow brClear fullWidth vertAlignT allAroundPad">
        <div class="setFloatL hidOverflow vertAlignT" style="width: 55%;">Login User: </div>
        <div class="setFloatL hidOverflow vertAlignT" style="width: 45%; color: #FFF;"><asp:Label ID="lblUserN" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidOverflow brClear fullWidth vertAlignT allAroundPad">
        <div class="setFloatL hidOverflow vertAlignT" style="width: 55%;">Workgroups: </div>
        <div class="setFloatL hidOverflow vertAlignT" style="width: 45%; color: #FFF;">
            <ul class="ulO" id="ulO" runat="server">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidOverflow brClear fullWidth vertAlignT allAroundPad" id="dvAdmin" runat="server">
        <div class="setFloatL hidOverflow vertAlignT" style="width: 55%;">Admin Status: </div>
        <div class="setFloatL hidOverflow vertAlignT" style="width: 45%; color: #FFF;"><asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgIsAdmin" ClientIDMode="Static" ImageUrl="~/theImages/admin_yes.png" CssClass="adminImg" /></div>
    </div>
    <img src="../theImages/preloader_small.gif" style="position: absolute; left: -22px; top: -22px;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with this working?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tu3zkapp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this using position values and negative positions.

[See the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8twajak/)

```
.box {
    position: relative;
}    

.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    left: -30px;
}
```

And the important part of the example in the code above. The `.box` is `position: relative;` - the image (which could be any HTML element of course) is `position: absolute;` and the absolutely positioned element can then be positioned using `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` or `z-index` properties exactly where you want it. You might need `z-index` if something else was overlaying it to ensure it is on top.

Position absolute always positions the element at co-ordinates relative to the next item up the DOM tree where the position is set to relative or absolute, meaning that the position will remain set regardless of how the internal `.box` HTML changes. These co-ordinates default to 0x and 0y.

Comment: the css box is free flowing, which means it is displayed on top of other content and hence why the absolute is necessary.

Comment: actually it will work with position: relative too, but you won't be able to put anything else first in the HTML!

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tu3zkapp/1/. The popup is displayed after hovering over an icon (not the correct placement but used for demo only)

Comment: I got it. I have to have the overall as absolute, then relative the entire box inside and then absolute to make it work?

Comment: container relative (or absolute), then image absolute with top and left set negative in order to have it over the top left corner.